# Why do installed fonts disappear after reboot?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, group-policy, font

At my place of employment we have designers who have to be able to install fonts to complete their work so I have given them write access to %sysroot%\fonts and to %sysroot%\system32\FNTCACHE.DAT through GPO and they can install and use fonts fine but after a restart these fonts disappear. Anyone have any idea why?

Windows 2003 Server running AD as PDC.
Windows XP clients.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you install fonts information also gets written to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`, so they will also need write access to that key.

Comment: Brilliant, added that to GPO. Will test ASAP. Thanks a lot!